# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named is defined

Tags: scala, scala-collections, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a question please: 
i would like to read multiple xml files (file1.xml, file2.xml....), for each file i read in memory then i edit and send request. for reading and editing its work fine without any problem, but when i send request:

```
//some declarations
 .......
var payload=""
 try{
myscenario= scenario ("scenario Name")
.exec{mysession : Session =>
//open files, list all files

for (file <-listofmyfile) {

//some regex that i reuse in payload
// payload contains the change that i would like to add for each xml file

payload=(// some function and text message.... "XXX")
}
mysession
}
.exec("protocol used".requestReply.message(StringBody( session => 
 session(payload).as[String]))
.check(substring("XXX"))
 )
 }

setUp(myscenario.inject....)}
```

i get this 2 errors :

```
[ERROR] i.g.c.s.w.BufferedFileChannelWriter - Buffer overflow, you shouldn't be logging that much data. Truncating.
[ERROR] i.g.t.a.RequestReply - crashed on session Session
```

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'payload' is defined

Comment: I don't know much about Gatling, but is there definitely a `payload` defined in all of your XML files?

Comment: payload is the content of xml files+ some functions (like generate actual date hour...), and some headers. i mean payload its what i want to edit in my xml files

Comment: so what i would like to do is to open each xml file and edit then send request

Comment: after some changes, now i am able to run my code but he send all files at the same time. What i want is to send each request separately, i think that i have to do some change (like loop or something) at : .exec("protocol used".requestReply.message(StringBody( session => 
 session(payload).as[String]))
.check(substring("XXX")). But i don´t know how to do that, maybe the use of Headers..... Maps (doc Gatling). Any idea please